# Code setting item price to 0

Tags: php

alright, these two functions refuse to work properly for some reason and i cannot figure out why. They work fine if used outside of an active database (I'ved tested it and am testing it right now)
but for some reason the second they're getting their information from the database, they zero out the price that's supposed to be updated; eg where a price should go up to say, 20 dollars from 4, it goes to zero and then next time it updates goes to the next number in the line.

```
private function updatePrice($iid, $price, $purchased)
{
    if($price >= 0)
    {
        $price = abs($price);
    }
    else
    {
        $price = $this->getItemStats($iid);
        $price = abs($price['base']);
    }
        $sql = "UPDATE store SET item_price = :price, available = available-:purchased  WHERE iid = :iid";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $que->bindParam('price', $price);
        $que->bindParam('iid', $iid);
        $que->bindParam('purchased', $purchased);
        try{$que->execute(); if($que) { return true; } else { echo "FUCK"; exit; } }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage(); exit;}
}
function getSupplyDemand($purchased, $iid)
{
    $sql = "SELECT available, number, item_base_price, iid FROM store WHERE iid = :iid";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('iid', $iid);
    try{ $que->execute();
        if($que)
        {
            while($row = $que->fetch())
            {
                $Quantity =$row[0];
                $Supply = $row[1];
                $price = $row[2];
                $iid = $row[3];
                $price = abs(($price * $purchased)*($Quantity - $Supply)/.25);
                    if($this->updatePrice($iid, $price, $purchased))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Somethign went wrong";
                        exit;
                    }
            }
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){}   
}
```

Comment: have you checked to see if `$purchased` or `($Quantity - $Supply)` are ever 0?

Comment: Neither of them should ever be 0. Though that would be the only reasonable explaination. i'm triple checking to see if maybe the code isn't firing in the right sequence and the items aren't being removed from the inventory before the update

Comment: Add a print statement just before the call and test it. Try printing those two values and seeing what they are.

Comment: Don't ever throw away exceptions. If you're not actually going to deal with them, simply omit the `try .. catch` blocks. Also, why are you using `return` in a loop?

Comment: What's your database schema (`DESC TABLE mytable`)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Once again it was something simple that i just overthought. I wasn't calling my functions in the proper order therefore the Number and Available were the same and removed from one another thus cancling out the whole price.